# Tree using Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, trees

I want to to reduce the size of the node to which they perceived better in my presentation; the problem is that the nodes are overlap.

I have the code from [Drawing a tree where many nodes have the same child in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59140/3235) :

```
  \begin{tikzpicture} [sibling distance=1.5cm]
      \node [size=0.3cm](topnode) at (0,5) { {\{\{1\}\{2\}\}\{3\}\{4\}}\} } 
      child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,2\}\{3\}\{4\}}\}} }
      child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,3\}\{2\}\{4\}}\}} }
      child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,4\}\{2\}\{3\}}\}} }
      child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{2,3\}\{1\}\{4\}}\}} }
      child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{2,4\}\{1\}\{3\}}\}} }
      child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{3,4\}\{1\}\{2\}}\}} }
      ;


      \node[minimum width=3cm](bottomnode) {\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}} [grow'=up]
      child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,2,3\}\{4\}}\}} }
      child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,2,4\}\{3\}}\}} }
      child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,2\}\{3,4\}}\}} }
      child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,3,4\}\{2\}}\}} }
      child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,3\}\{2,4\}}\}} }
      child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,4\}\{2,3\}}\}} }
      child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{2,3,4\}\{1\}}\}} }
      ;
      \foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
      \draw  [blue](topnode-1) -- (bottomnode-\x);
      }

      \foreach \x in {1,4,5}{
      \draw (topnode-2) -- (bottomnode-\x);
      }

      \foreach \x in {2,4,6}{
      \draw  [red] (topnode-3) -- (bottomnode-\x);
      }
      \foreach \x in {2,4,6}{
      \draw  [red] (topnode-3) -- (bottomnode-\x);
      }

      \foreach \x in {1,6,7}{
      \draw  [blue](topnode-4) -- (bottomnode-\x);
      }

      \foreach \x in {2,7,5}{
      \draw  [red](topnode-5) -- (bottomnode-\x);
      }

      \foreach \x in {3,4,7}{
      \draw (topnode-6) -- (bottomnode-\x);
      }

      \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to reduce the font size of nodes. You can do it by introducing:

```
\tikzset{every node/.append style={font=\tiny}}
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{TITLE}


\begin{tikzpicture} [sibling distance=1.5cm]
\tikzset{every node/.append style={font=\tiny}}
      \node [minimum size=0.3cm](topnode) at (0,5) { {\{\{1\}\{2\}\}\{3\}\{4\}}\} } 
      child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,2\}\{3\}\{4\}}\}} }
      child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,3\}\{2\}\{4\}}\}} }
      child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,4\}\{2\}\{3\}}\}} }
      child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {{\{\{2,3\}\{1\}\{4\}}\}} }
      child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {{\{\{2,4\}\{1\}\{3\}}\}} }
      child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {{\{\{3,4\}\{1\}\{2\}}\}} }
      ;


      \node[minimum width=3cm](bottomnode) {\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}} [grow'=up]
      child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,2,3\}\{4\}}\}} }
      child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,2,4\}\{3\}}\}} }
      child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,2\}\{3,4\}}\}} }
      child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,3,4\}\{2\}}\}} }
      child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,3\}\{2,4\}}\}} }
      child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,4\}\{2,3\}}\}} }
      child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {{\{\{2,3,4\}\{1\}}\}} }
      ;
      \foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
      \draw  [blue](topnode-1) -- (bottomnode-\x);
      }

      \foreach \x in {1,4,5}{
      \draw (topnode-2) -- (bottomnode-\x);
      }

      \foreach \x in {2,4,6}{
      \draw  [red] (topnode-3) -- (bottomnode-\x);
      }
      \foreach \x in {2,4,6}{
      \draw  [red] (topnode-3) -- (bottomnode-\x);
      }

      \foreach \x in {1,6,7}{
      \draw  [blue](topnode-4) -- (bottomnode-\x);
      }

      \foreach \x in {2,7,5}{
      \draw  [red](topnode-5) -- (bottomnode-\x);
      }

     \foreach \x in {3,4,7}{
     \draw (topnode-6) -- (bottomnode-\x);
      }

      \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which leads to:

[image]

Notice that in your example I had compilation problems due to the option `size=` which I turned into `minimum size=`.

Comment: I find it very hard to see where one node ends and the next one starts. I added `rotate=10` to the nodes style to make it better distinguishable.