# Organization of two graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf

How it is possible to represent two graphs created with TikZ in the same figure?

The source code for a graph is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{TITLE}

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
              \begin{tikzpicture} [sibling distance=1.5cm]

    %          \node [size=0.3cm](topnode) at (0,5) {\{1,2,3\}} 
          \node (topnode) at (0,5) {\{1,2,3\}} 
              child { node[size=0.3cm] {\{1,2\}\{3\}}}
              child { node[size=0.3cm] {\{1,3\}\{2\}}}
              child { node[size=0.3cm] {\{1\}\{2,3\}}}
              ;
              \node [size=0.3cm](topnode) {\{1\}\{2\}\{3\}}
    %         \node[minimum width=3cm]  at (0,5) {\{\{1,2,3\}\}}
              ;
              \foreach \x in {-3}{
              \draw  (topnode-1) -- (bottomnode-\x);
              \draw  (topnode-3) -- (bottomnode-\x);
              \draw  (topnode-2) -- (bottomnode-\x);
              }

              \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

like that

[image]

Comment: Please, edit/rephrase your question. It is unclear what you refer to.

Comment: Please turn the example into a full compilable document, starting from `\documentclass`. Also, please explain in more detail what exactly it is you're trying to change. There is no matrix in your code, what are you referring to?

Comment: That edit has not really helped to make the question clearer. Please complete your code to make a *full* document, and *clearly explain* what you want to achieve. A single sentence is not enough in this case.

Comment: Please make sure your code is compilable. The `figure` environment is not closed, the `size` key isn't defined, the `topnode` is defined twice but the `bottomnode` is missing. Also, again: Please explain what you want to achieve. It is not clear from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s a simple observation but you can add to useful @ClaudioFiandrino's answer the possibility of insert both graphs inside the same `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}` with the environment `\begin{scope}[shift={(5,0)}] ... \end{scope}` to separate them:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{TITLE}

\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture} [sibling distance=1.5cm]
 \node (topnode) at (0,5) {1}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {2}}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {3}}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {4}}
    ;
  \node [minimum size=0.3cm](bottomnode) {5};
  \draw  (topnode-1) -- (bottomnode);
  \draw  (topnode-3) -- (bottomnode);
  \draw  (topnode-2) -- (bottomnode);

  \begin{scope}[shift={(5,0)}]

  \node (topnode) at (0,5) {1}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {2}}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {3}}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {4}}
    ;
  \node [minimum size=0.3cm](bottomnode) {5};
  \draw  (topnode-1) -- (bottomnode);
  \draw  (topnode-3) -- (bottomnode);
  \draw  (topnode-2) -- (bottomnode);

  \end{scope}

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}

 \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Proceeding in this way, you can handle the relative position of one graph with respect to the other and not just in x-axis direction. (The image in this case is the same as the shown before by Claudio.)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to guess the request and to reproduce the picture uploaded.

For that example, it is not needed the exact syntax of code taken from [Drawing a tree where many nodes have the same child in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59140/drawing-a-tree-where-many-nodes-have-the-same-child-in-tikz#59145) and [Tree using Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59418/tree-using-latex/#59421), so in my answer I simplified it.

Basically, if the question was: "how to place these two graphs side by side", you can adopt two approaches:

1. insert the two pictures side by side (maybe with an `\hspace` to separate them);
2. use the `columns` environment.

The right method depends on your needs: if you have just to display the two pictures you can use the second one, while if you need to insert also some text maybe the first one is better.

> Method 1

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{TITLE}

\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture} [sibling distance=1.5cm]
 \node (topnode) at (0,5) {1}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {2}}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {3}}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {4}}
    ;
  \node [minimum size=0.3cm](bottomnode) {5};
  \draw  (topnode-1) -- (bottomnode);
  \draw  (topnode-3) -- (bottomnode);
  \draw  (topnode-2) -- (bottomnode);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \hspace{1cm}
 \begin{tikzpicture} [sibling distance=1.5cm]
  \node (topnode) at (0,5) {1}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {2}}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {3}}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {4}}
     ;
  \node [minimum size=0.3cm](bottomnode) {5};
  \draw  (topnode-1) -- (bottomnode);
  \draw  (topnode-3) -- (bottomnode);
  \draw  (topnode-2) -- (bottomnode);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

> Method 2

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{TITLE}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture} [sibling distance=1.5cm]
  \node (topnode) at (0,5) {1}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {2}}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {3}}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {4}}
     ;
 \node [minimum size=0.3cm](bottomnode) {5};
  \draw  (topnode-1) -- (bottomnode);
  \draw  (topnode-3) -- (bottomnode);
  \draw  (topnode-2) -- (bottomnode);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{column} 
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture} [sibling distance=1.5cm]
  \node (topnode) at (0,5) {1}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {2}}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {3}}
     child { node[minimum size=0.3cm] {4}}
     ;
 \node [minimum size=0.3cm](bottomnode) {5};
  \draw  (topnode-1) -- (bottomnode);
  \draw  (topnode-3) -- (bottomnode);
  \draw  (topnode-2) -- (bottomnode);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{column} 
\end{columns} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]