# Draw Tree using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drawing a tree where many nodes have the same child in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59140/drawing-a-tree-where-many-nodes-have-the-same-child-in-tikz)

I'm trying the draw a tree using the `tikz` package,

```
          \begin{center} 
          \begin{tikzpicture} [sibling distance=1.5cm]

          \node [size=0.3cm](topnode) at (0,5) { {\{\{1\}\{2\}\}\{3\}}\} } 
          child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,2\}\{3\}}\}} }
          child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{1,3\}\{2\}}\}} }
          child { node[size=0.3cm] {{\{\{2,3\}\{1\}}\}} }
          ;
          \node [size=0.3cm](topnode) {\{\{1,2,3\}\}}
%         \node[minimum width=3cm]  at (0,5) {\{\{1,2,3\}\}}
          ;
          \foreach \x in {-3}{
          \draw  (topnode-1) -- (bottomnode-\x);
          \draw  (topnode-3) -- (bottomnode-\x);
          \draw  (topnode-2) -- (bottomnode-\x);
          }

          \end{tikzpicture}
          \end{center}
```

[image]

My problem is how to approach a node (level) and how to connect the parent node to the node in level 3.

Comment: You can put a single node instead of a tree and draw the connections. In fact this is the same question with the previous one that you linked to.

Comment: Does [Drawing a tree where many nodes have the same child in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59140/drawing-a-tree-where-many-nodes-have-the-same-child-in-tikz) solve your problem? If not, please specify why it doesn't. Also, your code samples should always be complete compilable documents (starting from `\documentclass`).