# I'm getting the error: ! Paragraph ended before \@@label was complete

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees, tikz-qtree

I've scoured this forum and it looks to me like I'm setting up the tree correctly, but I'm still getting this error, I have

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
```

in the header.

Here is the code that is causing the problem:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\Tree 
[.{Boolean Groups}
    [.{Abelian Groups}
        [.Groups]
    ]
    [.{Class 3} 
        [.{Class 5}]
        [.{Class 1}]
        [.{Class 2}]
        [.{Class 4}]
    ]
]

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 25):

Get used to this error, it's a common one with `tikz-qtree`: `tikz-qtree` requires a space before a node's contents and its closing `]`.  So you need to insert some spaces before each `]` in your tree.

```
\Tree 
[.{Boolean Groups}
    [.{Abelian Groups}
        [.Groups ] % Here
    ]
    [.{Class 3} 
        [.{Class 5} ] % Here etc.
        [.{Class 1} ]
        [.{Class 2} ]
        [.{Class 4} ]
    ]
]
```

If you need to connect particular nodes in the tree with each other, you can add explicit `\node` commands and then use regular TikZ drawing commands to connect them.  To connect 'Abelian Groups' to 'Class 5' make them each nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\Tree 
[.{Boolean Groups}
    [.\node (A) {Abelian Groups};
        [.Groups ]
    ]
    [.{Class 3} 
        [.\node (5) {Class 5}; ]
        [.{Class 1} ]
        [.{Class 2} ]
        [.{Class 4} ]
    ]
]
\draw (A) -- (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Awesome thanks that worked, another question, right now I have a line from class 3 to class 5, is there an easy way to add a line from Abelian Groups to Class 5 as well. Most of the info I can find online makes it look like I have to make an arrow or some other thing that doesn't look like all the other lines.

For example, I found this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59140/drawing-a-tree-where-many-nodes-have-the-same-child-in-tikz

but it looks to be more complicated than I need.  Or is this the easiest way?

Comment: @Marco See my update.

Comment: Definitely +1. This is fantastic. Spent at least 45 minutes trying to figure what I did wrong; this answer helped immensely.

Answer (score 5):

`forest` allows you to draw trees using a slightly more intuitive syntax, I think:

- no need to leave spaces before the closing bracket, although it isn't a problem if you do so, either;
- no need to preface a new sub-tree with a dot - just use brackets with nesting to represent the tree structure;
- no need to explicitly make things TikZ nodes in order to name them - all nodes are TikZ nodes and can be given a name using `name=` and, if necessary, extra names using `alias=`.

In the following code, I've also used a `phantom` node in order to move the bottom left node outwards, so that the connection between `abelian groups` and `class 5` is displayed more naturally.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt, varwidth, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
    }
    [Boolean Groups
        [Abelian Groups, name=abelian groups
            [Groups]
            [, phantom]
        ]
        [Class 3
            [Class 5, name=class 5]
            [Class 1]
            [Class 2]
            [Class 4]
        ]
    ]
    \draw (abelian groups.south) -- (class 5);
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: forest tree]