# tikz-qtree: Beginners Problems

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, qtree

Hello im not a Linguist and have some trouble with trees.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=up]
        \Tree [.a 
                [.b 
                    [.c [.d e]]
                    [.f g]
                ]                       
            ]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Why wouldn't this work?
Im running into problems only when i want to let a node have on single node from which the tree then branches out farther

like:

```
  /  b   
a
  \  c
```

is okay but:

```
      /  c
a - b 
      \  d
```

is not

Comment: I think you need a space or newline after `e` and `g`. If I do that, it works fine. EDIT: Welcome to TeX SE!

Comment: Is it the same problem as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63008/im-getting-the-error-paragraph-ended-before-label-was-complete?

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=up]
        \Tree [.a
                [.b
                    [.c
                      [.d e
                      ]
                    ]
                    [.f g
                    ]
                ]
            ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Tree]

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility with [`forest`](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest) package.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={grow'=90}
        [a[b[c[d [e]]]
                 [f [g]]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]