# What am I doing wrong with the qtree function?

Tags: errors, trees, tikz-qtree

I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with my code, but no matter what I do it does not compile.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree, qtree, graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\author{My Name}
\title{title}
  \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \pagebreak
      \begin{tikzpicture}
          \Tree[.sentence
           [.{noun phrase}
             [.article the]
             [.adjective young]
             [.noun ball]]
           [.{verb phrase}
             [.verb caught]
             [.{noun phrase}
               [.article the]
               [.noun man]]]]
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Can you show us a complete yet minimal document ([minimal working example—or MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)) that shows the problem? And ideally the exact error message you get? Because right now all we can say is that there is no `\documentclass` command in your code nor a `document` environment.

Comment: Thanks. I am new, so I don't know what the bare minimum that people ask from code.

Comment: This is probably the most common error in `tikz-qtree`. You must have a space between a terminal node and its closing bracket.  This is a duplicate of [I'm getting the error: ! Paragraph ended before \@@label was complete](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63008). Additionally, you shouldn't use `qtree` if you are also using `tikz-qtree`.  Just use `tikz-qtree`.